# determinating if the input is even or odd numbers

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to write a program in python that asks the user to input a set of numbers of 1's and 0's and I want the program to tell me if I have and even number of zeros or an odd number of zeros or no zero's at all.  Thanks for your help!!

```
forstate = "start"
curstate = "start"
trans = "none"
value = 0


print "Former state....:", forstate
print "Transition....:", trans
print "Current state....", curstate
    while curstate != "You hav and even number of zeros":
        trans = raw_input("Input a 1 or a 0: ")
        if trans == "0" and value <2:
            value = value + 1
            forstate = curstate
        elif trans == "1" and value < 2:
            value = value + 0
            forstate = curstate
        curstate = str(value) + "  zeros"
        if value >= 2:
            curstate = "You have and even number of zeros"
        print "former state ...:", forstate
        print "Transition .....:", trans
        print "Current state....", curstate
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Thirdtimesacharm! What you have gotinated so far?

Comment: ** so far this is what i have but this only works if the user inputs one number at a time.  I want in so the user can input numerous numbers.  Also this only works for two zeros and I want it to work for and infinate number of zeros.

Comment: forstate = "start"
curstate = "start"
trans = "none"
value = 0
print "Former state....:", forstate
print "Transition....:", trans
print "Current state....", curstate

Comment: while curstate != "You have and even number of zeros":
    trans = raw_input("Input a 1 or a 0: ")
    if trans == "0" and value <2:            value = value + 1
            forstate = curstate
        elif trans == "1" and value < 2:
            value = value + 0
            forstate = curstate
        curstate = str(value) + "  zeros"
        if value >= 2:
            curstate = "You have and even number of zeros"
        print "former state ...:", forstate
        print "Transition .....:", trans
        print "Current state....", curstate

Comment: @Richie Click on the link "edit" right below your original question and place the code there.

Comment: I think I've spent too much time on codegolf.stackexchange.com that I now have the urge to golf everything in sight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do a finite state machine?

```
try:
    inp = raw_input
except NameError:
    inp = input

def getInt(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(inp(msg))
        except ValueError:
            pass

START, ODD, EVEN = range(3)
state_next = [ODD, EVEN, ODD]
state_str  = ['no zeros yet', 'an odd number of zeros', 'an even number of zeros']

state = START
while True:
    num = getInt('Enter a number (-1 to exit)')

    if num==-1:
        break
    elif num==0:
        state = state_next[state]

    print 'I have seen {0}.'.format(state_str[state])
```

**Edit:**

```
try:
    inp = raw_input
except NameError:
    inp = input

START, ODD, EVEN = range(3)
state_next = [ODD, EVEN, ODD]
state_str  = ['no zeros yet', 'an odd number of zeros', 'an even number of zeros']

def reduce_fn(state, ch):
    return state_next[state] if ch=='0' else state

state = reduce(reduce_fn, inp('Enter at own risk: '), START)
print "I have seen " + state_str[state]
```

Comment: ha ha yes i'm trying to do a finite state machine for my engineering class, and this works great but my teacher wants the user to input a strand of numbers such as : 01010100, and then  output if that list of numbers has even or odd zeros in it.

Comment: @Richie: y'know, that might have been *useful information* in the original question...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like homework, or worse an interview questions, but this will get you started.

```
def homework(s):
 counter = 0
 if '0' in s:
   for i in s:
     if i == '0':
       counter = counter + 1
 return counter
```

don't forget this part over here

```
def odd_or_even_or_none(num):
  if num == 0:
    return 'This string contains no zeros'
  if num % 2 == 0
    return 'This string contains an even amount of zeros'
  else:
    return 'This string contains an odd amount of zeros'
```

if you call homework and give it a string of numbers it will give you back the number of 0

```
homework('101110101')
```

now that you know how many 0s you need to call odd_or_even_or_none with that number

```
odd_or_even_or_none(23)
```

so the solution looks like this

```
txt = input('Feed me numbers:  ')
counter = str( homework(txt) )
print odd_or_even_or_none(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    inp = raw_input
except NameError:
    inp = input

zeros = sum(ch=='0' for ch in inp('Can I take your order? '))

if not zeros:
    print "none"
elif zeros%2:
    print "odd"
else:
    print "even"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to your problem is just to count the zeros, then print a suitable message. `num_zeros = input_stream.count('0')`

If you're going to build a finite state machine to learn how to write one, then you'll learn more writing a generic FSM and using it to solve your particular problem. Here's my attempt - note that all the logic for counting the zeros is encoded in the states and their transitions.

```
class FSMState(object):
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.transition = {}
        self.description = description
    def set_transitions(self, on_zero, on_one):
        self.transition['0'] = on_zero
        self.transition['1'] = on_one

def run_machine(state, input_stream):
    """Put the input_stream through the FSM given."""
    for x in input_stream:
        state = state.transition[x]
    return state

# Create the states of the machine.
NO_ZEROS = FSMState('No zeros')
EVEN_ZEROS = FSMState('An even number of zeros')
ODD_ZEROS = FSMState('An odd number of zeros')

# Set up transitions for each state
NO_ZEROS.set_transitions(ODD_ZEROS, NO_ZEROS)
EVEN_ZEROS.set_transitions(ODD_ZEROS, EVEN_ZEROS)
ODD_ZEROS.set_transitions(EVEN_ZEROS, ODD_ZEROS)

result = run_machine(NO_ZEROS, '01011001010')
print result.description
```